# Windows server running Milestone security

Tags: networking, security

I’m the admin of a small network on a ship. We have a virtual server running windows server 2016. It’s for control of our security cameras.
Connected to the VM are 6 intel NUC PCs. Every time we change time zone, I have to go to each machine and change the time zone manually. As it doesn’t pick up a change time zone request from the NTP.

Is there a setting to force time zone changes from the server to run on all the connected NUCs? I am also having to do this manually for the cameras too.

Basically I’d like to know if there’s a way I can change time zone on the server, and have it update to all the devices connected to it. Can’t seem to find anything on it.

Comment: It sounds like you need a [NTP Time Server](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/products/ntp-time-server.htm), or perhaps a better solution, use Zulu or UTC, and just ignore timezones all together

Comment: Have you configured the NUCs to get their time from your server, specifically, the operating system hosting the virtual machine?